# Changing the Default Plane Texture

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5.1.1f1 and I am wondering why the default `plane` game object that I create as ground/floor has its `Material` component grayed out?

How can I change its texture then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new material and apply it to the plane game object, then it should be possible to change the new material's texture.

Comment: Apply how? I understand you can either click on the little circle and choose your desired material or drag&drop the material on the material component, but given that it is all grayed out, I don't know how to apply. Could you elaborate please? Thanks

Comment: The material editor is grayed out because the default material cannot be changed, so creating a new material overcomes this issue as you can edit the new material in the Unity Inspector panel.